# Icon of Playonlinux

Tags: 14.04, playonlinux

I install playonlinux

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

but i did not see playonlinux icon after searching.

so i run this command again and it says that.

> ```
> playonlinux is already the newest version (4.2.10-2ubuntu0.1).
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 544 not upgraded.
> ```

Again i searched,but there is no icon.
So what should i do ??

I was following this video [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdsTVpRp2yM)

Comment: Should we be watching this video? Please post the steps taken...

Comment: step 1 -   `sudo apt-get update` , step 2- `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`  in next step to searching the app playonlinx but there is no icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options here:

- On MATE and GNOME FlashBack it is in *Applications* in *Games* category, *PlayOnLinux* [image: PlayOnLinux].
- On Unity you can search for it by name with (open Dash with <kbd>Super</kbd> key and type *playonlinux*).
- If can not find it try to launch it from terminal with `playonlinux` command or from *Run* with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.